# 4 Talking Clams, and treasure

Tags: logical-deduction, story

After going to the depths of the ocean, you have finally reached it: the ultimate treasure of the world. However, when you go inside the sacred treasure room, you are presented with the Four Clams. They had an argument since one of them has angered Poseidon, the king of the sea. So, they decided that if you can tell who angered Poseidon, then you shall keep the treasure.

Based on the four situations, you should be able to decipher who is the one telling the truth and catch the clam/s who angered the King. Note that First, Second, Third, and Fourth will be called Harrold, Henry, Harry, and Hammy, respectively.

First Clam:

> I was just cleaning my pearl, when, I heard Poseidon get really angry. I rushed outside to see the Poseidon angry, shouting "Hammy, Hammy! Why did you kill my beautiful daughter!" I also saw Hammy running away from the palace, from behind.

Second Clam:

> I was in the hut, resting when I heard Poseidon get really angry. I just stayed in the hut, because I was really tired, when: "Harrold, why did you kill my beautiful daughter!" It was not me who did it, but neither did Harry do it, for he with me in the hut.

Third Clam:

> I was with Henry, resting in the hut as well when I heard Poseidon get really angry. I went out of the hut when Poseidon screamed: "why...kill...daughter". I did not know what he said, but I heard a -"har" sound at the start of the sentence. I was wearing ear-muffs at that time.

Fourth Clam:

> I was just in the kitchen, cooking my food for a snack when I heard: "Hammy, Hammy, why did you kill my daughter!" And I was so scared that I was going to be killed, I hid in a sea-bush. I realized Poseidon was not there anymore, so I just left my hiding spot. I definitely did not do it.

So, with all that information, Poseidon being correct, who was the killer.

Comment: There can be no answer, if the first 3 clams claimed that poseidon became angry, none of them can be telling the truth, for if one did then 3 would be telling the truth. That leaves us with 4, but he was telling the truth then so would 1 because both if them claimed poseidon said the same thing, so 4 cannot be telling the truth. So no one is telling the truth is the answer.

Comment: all 4 of them were the ones that angered the king

Comment: *I also saw Hammy running away from the palace* Lol I just imagined how a clam is running away.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a cipher hidden somewhere with the answer, but absent that, taking this at face value, how about:

> HARRY angered the King

> The puzzle implies exactly one clam is telling the truth ("the one telling the truth").
>  If Clam 1 or 4 is telling the truth, then they both are as they both accuse Hammy. So they are both lying and it is not Hammy.
>  If Clam 2 is telling the truth and Harrold angered the King, then Clam 3 is also telling the truth as their story is in agreement with that. So Clam 2 is lying and it is not Harrold.
>  Clam 3 is the only clam left who could be telling the truth. They cannot be accusing Harrold per above, so the 'har' sound they heard must have been "Harry".
>  This would mean HARRY angered the King and was the killer.

Answer (score -2):

I think the forth clam teamed up with one of the other three, and they are all trying to avoid blame. The forth clam is trying to avoid getting caught by being the most obvious answer. Their associate is helping cause confusion by naming someone not associated with the reason Poseidon is angry.

Comment: Why? Please justify instead of just giving your theory. Why does this make sense in the context of the puzzle?